# wp_verify_nonce() via REST always returns false

Tags: nonce

I'm trying to create and verify nonce, and I did it almost the same way as described in [wp_create_nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_nonce).

I believe it's related to REST api, but not sure where to investigate?

How I create nonce:

(I have an REST function that returns codes to draw up HTML, which properly draws up the HTML, where the resulting value of wp_create_nonce() filled up properly)

```
/***
 * Display customers/vendors in table format
 ***/

if( !function_exists( 'fnc_view_customer_vendor_in_table_format' ) ) {
    /**
     * @param WP_REST_Request $request
     * @return mixed|string|void
     */
    function fnc_view_customer_vendor_in_table_format(WP_REST_Request $request ) {

        $_search_name = $request['_search_name'];
        $_posttype = $request['_posttype'];

        if( $_posttype == null ) {
            $result = array( 'msg' => 'ERROR: Please try again', 'error' => true );
            return json_encode( $result );
        }

        $data = '<table class="table widefat table-striped">';
        $data .= '<thead>';
        $data .= '<tr>';
        $data .= '<th class="col-name">Name</th>';
        $data .= '<th class="col-phone">Phone</th>';
        $data .= '<th class="col-email">Fax</th>';
        $data .= '<th class="col-email">Email</th>';
        $data .= '<th class="col-website">Website</th>';
        $data .= '<th class="col-action">Actions</th>';
        $data .= '</tr>';
        $data .= '</thead>';
        $data .= '<tbody>';

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => $_posttype,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        );

        if( $_search_name ) {
            $search_args = array(
                's' => $_search_name
            );
            $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $search_args );
        }

        $posts = get_posts( $args );

        $del_page = get_permalink( fnc_get_id_by_slug_and_posttype( 'delete-instance', 'page' ) );

        foreach( $posts as $post ) :

            $post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID );

            $data .= '<tr>';

            $data .= '<th class="col-name">';
            $data .= get_the_title( $post->ID );
            $data .= '</th>';

            $data .='<th class="col-phone">';
            $data .= get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_phone', true );
            $data .= '</th>';

            $data .= '<th class="col-fax">';
            $data .= get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_fax', true );
            $data .= '</th>';

            $data .= '<th class="col-email">';
            $data .= get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_email', true );
            $data .= '</th>';

            $data .= '<th class="col-website">';
            $data .= '<a href="'.get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_website', true ).'" target = "_new">';
            $data .= get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_website', true );
            $data .= '</a>';
            $data .= '</th>';

            $data .='<th class="col-action">';
            $data .='<div class="col-action-btn">';
            $data .='<div class="col-action-edit">';
            $data .='<form action="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '" id="form-edit" name="form-edit" method="post">';
            $data .='<!-- Noncename needed to verify where the data originated -->';
            $data .= '<input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="'. wp_create_nonce( 'edit_post-'. $post->ID ) .'" />';
            $data .= '<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/test/lists/view-vendors" />';
            $data .= '<input type="hidden" id="post_id" name="post_id" value="'. $post->ID .'" />';
            $data .='<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="edit">';
            $data .='<input type="submit" class="btn btn-small" value="Edit">';
            $data .='</form>';
            $data .='</div>';
            /*
            $data .='<div class="col-action-delete">';
            $data .= '<form action="' . $del_page . '" id="form-delete" name="form-delete" method="post"  />';
            $data .= '<!-- Noncename needed to verify where the data originated -->';
            $data .= '<input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="'. wp_create_nonce() .'" />';
            $data .='<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="delete" />';
            $data .='<input type="hidden" name="del_post_id" value=" ' .$post->ID . '" />';
            $data .='<input type="hidden" name="del_post_type" value=" ' .$post_type . '" />';
            $data .='<input type="submit" class="btn btn-small" value="Delete" />';
            $data .='</form>';
            */
            $data .= '</th>';

            $data .= '</tr>';

        endforeach;

        $data .= '</tbody>';
        $data .= '</table>';

        $result = array( 'msg' => $data, 'error' => false );

        return json_encode( $result );

    }
}
```

How I validate nonce:

```
  // Nonce from other pages
  $nonce = $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'];
  $post_id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];

  print_r( $_POST );
  // prints Array ( [_wpnonce] => 47f80a1859 [_wp_http_referer] => /test/lists/view-vendors [post_id] => 19793 [mode] => edit )
  echo '<br/>';
  echo '<br/>';

  var_dump( wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'edit_post-'. $post_id ) );
  // prints bool(false)
  echo '<br/>';
  echo '<br/>';

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'edit_post-'. $post_id ) ) {

        print $GLOBALS['doumi']['nonce_fail_msg'];
        echo '</main></div>';
        get_footer();
        die();

    }
```

Comment: if it return a value it should not, it is very probable that you don't call it. set a "breakpoint" in the function to make sure you get there. most likely it is being overriden by some plugin

Comment: I did not install any plugin and I am pretty sure that my function is get called since the $_POST variables echo proper values right before wp_verify_nonce.

Comment: it is software engineering, not voodoo. If a function has a `return 4` and you get 1, it means that you called something else instead.

Comment: This post https://websupporter.net/blog/de/nonces-in-der-rest-api/ is in German language, but really helpful, and maybe readable for you with a translating service.

Comment: @bueltge Thanks for the advice,  but the thing is that I am preparing the code for echoing the nounce in REST, which is actually echoed in normal Wordpress page. So it' a bit different situation from the article you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

In line 3 of your form markup, you're passing two arguments to [`wp_create_nonce`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_nonce/) when it only accepts one. It's a simple typo. You'll want to concatenate the string like so:

```
wp_create_nonce( 'edit_post-'. $post->ID ) //dot instead of comma
```

EDIT: I'd suggest you give the nonce field a more specific name than `_wpnonce`, as this is the generic(default) Wordpress name for nonce fields, which means you probably have a conflict with other core nonces or a plugin nonce. Maybe try something like this:

```
// change the NONCE name to something unique
$data .= '<input type="hidden" id="wpse263026_nonce" name="wpse263026_nonce" value="'. wp_create_nonce( 'edit_post-'. $post->ID ) .'" />';
```

Comment: Corrected the typo from comma to dot, but it still yields EMPTY. The value of wp_create_nonce() in the function is the same as the value of $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'] in the validator, and the value of $post->ID in the function is the same as the value of $_REQUEST['post_id']. BUt still it isn't working.

Comment: Can you do `var_dump($result);` instead of `echo` and post the results?

Comment: Well, I thought `$result` is empty or null since `print_r( $result )` didn't yield anything. Now it yields `bool(false)` with `var_dump( $result )`. I didn't know `print_r` and `var_dump` give different results. Anyways, I'm not sure why it yields `bool(false)`...

Comment: An empty string equates to `false` in PHP, and this is what I suspected. I will edit my answer to further help you

Comment: @Spartacua I tried many times with wp_nonce_field (), but it is not appended to $data. That is,  the return value (input code) of wp_nonce_field () is not added to a variable and my code is just interrupted there.

Comment: That's my bad. I didn't realize you were sending the form as JSON, when wp_nonce_field echoes out the inputs. Answer adjusted.